# Find a function that is close to the indicator function and infinite derivative

Tags: measure-theory, regularization

Good afternoon,

I need to show that there is a function $\gamma$ that is infinite derivative and where every element of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$  gives $\gamma (x) = 0$
Also, this function must respect this :
$\gamma (x) = 1, \left | x \right | \leqslant 1 ,  x \in  \mathbb{R}^n$

For now, I found that $\gamma (x) = \chi[0;1](\left | x \right |)$.
I guess I need to regularize my function, however I don't really know how to process...

If you can give me a hint, it would be nice

Comment: Take a look at [Bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Comment: Ok, I see. The function given as an example can help make a mollifier. But I'm not sure I need to calculate as I just need to prove that there is a function that can match with those conditions.

Comment: I think I did not take the right function since with a bump fuction I won't have $\gamma$ = 1 on both borders...